# SSO to any wso2 component using google/gmail acount

Tags: identity, federated-identity, wso2

I tried openID based SSO using the WSO2 and it worked fine. My use case requires to support SSO using both the google/gmail accounts as well as the application issued user accounts. Can WSO2 component be configured as relying party and google as the SSO provider.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need is a custom UserStoreManager that will authenticate users against google.

Identity server can be configured with multiple user stores.

I have not had much look implementing a custom UserStoreManager, although the wso2 source of course has implementations for LDAPReadWriteUserStoreManager and some others.